# Question on uniform continuity and metric spaces and complete metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

> Def: A function $f$ from a metric space $X$ to $Y$ is uniformly continuous if
>   given $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ s.t for $x,y\in X,  D(x,y)<\delta \to D(f(x),f(y))< \epsilon$.

Here is the quote from Sets and  Metric spaces by Kaplansky,
Pg 102

The idea behind this def. is that the epsilon-delta def. of continuity is applied globally, rather than one point at a time...Let us give an example to illustrate the point. As we shall see in Section 5.3,  no such example can be given with $X$ a closed interval - or any bounded closed set.

My understanding of this quote Kaplansky seems to be saying if we are dealing in $\mathbb R$ and some function $f$ on $X=[a,b]$ then $f$ is not uniformly continuous?

Isn’t this def pretty much the same intro analysis courses. Then the basic assumptions should hold for metric spaces as continuity does?

As far the example went to section 5.3 it is on compactness. The only Theorems it could apply is 73 or 67? But these are theorems and not examples per say..

Comment: You seem to be omitting some things. Is the example alluded to an example of a function which is not uniformly continuous? Because there is indeed a theorem stating that any continuous function from a compact metric space is uniformly continuous.

Comment: The section deals with Cauchy sequences and it’s consequences. For instance, convergent sequences are Cauchy ..
A space is complete if a Cauchy seq converges to some point in M...

Comment: Again, you are omitting the example, but I assume it is a continuous but not uniformly continuous map. Any continuous function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous, which is also a classic result in calculus called the Heine-Cantor theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem.

Comment: Yes, he is omissing a lot of thing! First of all @Shaggy quotes the wrong page, the correct one is 88 (2nd Edition). Kaplansky says **Let us give an example to illustrate the point. As we shall see in Section 5.3, no such example can be given with $X$ a closed interval - or any bounded closed set.** And then he gives the metric space $X=\{1, 1/2, 1/3,\dots, 1/n,\dots\}$.

Comment: @keen-amateur Thanks It allows me to do the examples.

Comment: I was quoting from the PDF ref , not the book page. X in this case is open. So Kaplansky seems to want you to work with open intervals. I can prove f is uniformly continuous by the def or Lipshitz condition and apply T 51 to it in that order. I think I seen one example to f(x)=$x^2$ I did the first part proved it was uniformly continuous...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the book, nor a PDF of it. But probably he gives an example like $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,1)$ to have a function that is continuous at each point but not uniformly continuous on its domain. $f(x)=x^2$ also works as such an example on $\Bbb R$ (or any unbounded real set), say (all in the standard metrics of course).

Later he will presumably prove the theorem that *any* continuous (i.e. normal, pointwise continuous) $f$ on a space $X$ that is **compact** is automatically uniformly continuous, a very useful and classic fact in analysis. So the examples he must ahve given earlier had a non-closed or non-bounded domain (in $\Bbb R$) as in the reals compactness can be shown to be equivalent to being closed and bounded.

Comment: It ‘s probably what he means . Thanks